# Remove brackets and number inside from string Python

Tags: python

I've seen a lot of examples on how to remove brackets from a string in Python, but I've not seen any that allow me to remove the brackets and a number inside of the brackets from that string.

For example, suppose I've got a string such as "abc[1]". How can I remove the "[1]" from the string to return just "abc"?

I've tried the following:

```
stringTest = "abc[1]"
stringTestWithoutBrackets = str(stringTest).strip('[]')
```

but this only outputs the string without the final bracket

> abc[1

I've also tried with a wildcard option:

```
stringTest = "abc[1]"
stringTestWithoutBrackets = str(stringTest).strip('[\w+\]')
```

but this also outputs the string without the final bracket

> abc[1

Comment: Why don't you think about ``regex``?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am looping over an XML document and I need to do some stuff with each node. Some nodes occur more than once in the document (as in their names) and as a result, `lxml` returns the name of the node as an array (which is fine). But in order to do some stuff that I'd like, I need to remove the array annotation.

Comment: @Adam looks like we have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. You should edit your post to explain your __real__ problem (as clearly as possible, with a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex but you need to use it with the `re` module:

```
re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', stringTest)
```

If the `[<number>]` part is always at the end of the string you can also strip via:

```
stringTest.rstrip('[0123456789]')
```

Though the latter version might strip beyond the `[` if the previous character is in the strip list too. For example in `"abc1[5]"` the `"1"` would be stripped as well.

Comment: @Adam But keep in mind, it's also the slowest approach. For simple string operations it's usually better to rely directly on the `str` methods. If you have only one (or a few) subscripts, the `rstrip` will be fastest since it only needs to allocate memory for one string opposed to `split` which creates two strings and one tuple. But it also runs the risk of stripping numbers from the variable names if this is relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions for that, but I think the easiest way would be to use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```py
>>> stringTest = "abc[1][2][3]"
>>> stringTest.split('[', maxsplit=1)[0]
'abc'
```

Comment: Maybe use `split` instead of `rsplit` in order to deal with an arbitrary number of subscripts like `abc[1][2][3]`?

Comment: @a_guest interesting point! As OP said in comments this is list subscript annotation, that indeed seems better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string has the format "text[number]" and you only want to keep the "text", then you could do:

```
stringTest = "abc[1]"
bracketBegin = stringTest.find('[')
stringTestWithoutBrackets = stringTest[:bracketBegin]
```